# Google Docs Section Break Page Setup

Tags: google-docs

Can page setup be performed on a section in Google Docs?

I create a document, and create a section break, then click File -> Page Setup, and click "apply to this section", but literally every option is greyed out so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a sample Google Doc, with the section break options not appearing:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MI5DCQIzwS_ws_Iw3m90lImg71fNCZaPkz_89Nb9y-A/edit?usp=sharing

[image: The page setup for a section is not available]

Comment: any screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is working as intended.

The description of the new feature only describes adjusting the margins either from the ruler or by using the Margin settings within Page setup.

Comment: Oh, that is surprising to me. Can you provide a link to the description?